# Como atribuir um valor tratado na função para o meu vetor?

Tags: c, array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define TAM_Min 1
#define TAM_Max 500

/*
Sintese
Objetivo: Classificar animais de um zoologico segundo seu peso
Entrada: Numeros de animais do zoologico, e para cada animal o numero de identificacao e o peso em gramas
SaÃ­da: Identificacao, peso do animal mais pesado, a identificacao e o peso do animal mais leve, e a quantidade
de animais de peso menor que o peso medio de todos os animais

*/

int le_valida_codigo_animal(int cod[], char titulo[]);
int le_valida_inteiro(int ValorMin, int ValorMax, char texto[]);


int main() {
    int i, num_animais, cod_animal[TAM_Max];
    float peso_animal[TAM_Max];

    //validar numero de animais
    printf("#--- Cadastro de animais ---#");
    num_animais =le_valida_inteiro(TAM_Min, TAM_Max, "\nDigite o numero de animais do zoologico:");

    for(i=1;i<=num_animais;i++){

        cod_animal[i] = le_valida_codigo_animal(cod_animal[i], "Digite o codigo de identificacao dos animais:");


        printf("Digite o peso (em gramas) do animal:");
        scanf("%d", &peso_animal[i]);
        system("cls");
    }

    return 0;
}

int le_valida_inteiro(int ValorMin, int ValorMax, char texto[]){
    int num_animais=0;
    do{

        printf(texto);
        scanf("%d", &num_animais);

        if(num_animais<ValorMin||num_animais >ValorMax){
            printf("\nValor invalido.\nDigite um numero ate 500!");
        }

    }while(num_animais<ValorMin||num_animais >ValorMax);
    return num_animais;
}

int le_valida_codigo_animal(int cod[], char titulo[]){

    char cod_an[0];

    do{
        printf(titulo);
        scanf("%d", &cod);
        if(cod == '\0'){
            printf("O codigo deve nao pode ser vazio!");
        }

    }while(cod == '\0');
}
```

Error recebido

> C:\Users\lain\Desktop\c.c In function 'main':
>   32    43  C:\Users\lain\Desktop\c.c   [Warning] passing argument 1 of
>   'le_valida_codigo_animal' makes pointer from integer without a cast
>   18    5   C:\Users\lain\Desktop\c.c   [Note] expected 'int *' but argument is
>   of type 'int' C:\Users\lain\Desktop\c.c   In function
>   'le_valida_codigo_animal': C:\Program
>   Files\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe   reopening
>   C:\Users\lain\Desktop\c.exe: Permission denied

Comment: Faltou colocar qual é o erro ou problema que você está enfrentando.

Comment: Dentro do for, aquele vetor recebendo o valor validado pela função. Veja o erro: C:\Users\lain\Desktop\c.c In function 'main':
32 43 C:\Users\lain\Desktop\c.c [Warning] passing argument 1 of 'le_valida_codigo_animal' makes pointer from integer without a cast
18 5 C:\Users\lain\Desktop\c.c [Note] expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int'
C:\Users\lain\Desktop\c.c In function 'le_valida_codigo_animal':
C:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe reopening C:\Users\lain\Desktop\c.exe: Permission denied

Comment: Desculpa aí falta de jeito para explicar. É a primeira vez que faço uma pergunta aqui no stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou dar uma melhorada no seu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define TAM_MIN 1
#define TAM_MAX 500

/*
Síntese
Objetivo: Classificar animais de um zoológico segundo seu peso.
Entrada: Números de animais do zoológico, e para cada animal,
         o número de identificação e o peso em gramas.
Saída: A identificação e peso do animal mais pesado, a identificação
       e o peso do animal mais leve, e a quantidade de animais de
       peso menor que o peso médio de todos os animais.
*/

int le_valida_codigo_animal(char *titulo);
int le_valida_inteiro(int valor_min, int valor_max, char *texto);

int main() {
    int cod_animal[TAM_MAX];
    float peso_animal[TAM_MAX];

    printf("#--- Cadastro de animais ---#");
    int num_animais = le_valida_inteiro(TAM_MIN, TAM_MAX, "\nDigite o número de animais do zoológico:");

    for (int i = 1; i <= num_animais; i++) {

        cod_animal[i] = le_valida_codigo_animal("Digite o codigo de identificacao dos animais:");

        printf("Digite o peso (em gramas) do animal:");
        scanf("%f", &peso_animal[i]);
        system("cls");
    }

    return 0;
}

int le_valida_inteiro(int valor_min, int valor_max, char *texto) {
    int num_animais = 0;

    while (1) {
        printf("%s", texto);
        scanf("%d", &num_animais);

        if (num_animais >= valor_min && num_animais <= valor_max) {
            return num_animais;
        }
        printf("\nValor invalido.\nDigite um número entre %d e %d!", valor_min, valor_max);    
    }
}

int le_valida_codigo_animal(char *titulo) {
    while (1) {
        int cod = 0;
        printf("%s", titulo);
        scanf("%d", cod);
        if (cod != 0) return cod;
        printf("O codigo deve nao pode ser vazio!");
    }
}
```

O principal problema é que a sua função `le_valida_codigo_animal` estava definida de forma errada. `int cod[]` como parâmetro é equivalente a `int *cod`. Quando você usa então `scanf("%d", &cod);`, ocorre que `cod` já é um ponteiro (ou seja, um endereço de memória), e portanto o correto seria `scanf("%d", cod);`. Ao usar `&cod`, você dá o endereço de um ponteiro, ou seja, um ponteiro para ponteiro, e isso não vai ser o que você quer.

Entretanto, ocorre que você quer retornar o código em `le_valida_codigo_animal`, então nem há motivo para recebê-lo como parâmetro.

Quanto a `printf(texto);`, o melhor é usar `printf("%s", texto);` porque assim você garante que o texto será reproduzido mesmo se ele conter coisas que poderiam ser confundidas com formatadores de string. Por exemplo, imagine um cenário que o `texto` fosse `"Concluido 50% ou mais"`. Nesse cenário, usar o `printf(texto);` daria pau porque esse "`%`" seria confundido como parte da string de formatação. A solução portanto é usar `printf("%s", texto);`.

Comment: Poxa, mano! Valeu mesmo por suas explicações. Vou terminar de escrever e código e caso surja alguma dúvida eu apareço por aqui. Eu já tava pensando em fazer outra coisa da vida... hahah

Comment: @LucasCorreia Se essa resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar. :)

Comment: O único problema é que você usou ponteiros. O meu professor proibiu o uso deles antes de nós vermos o assunto em sala de aula. De qualquer maneira, a sua ajuda me deu ânimo para estudar.

Comment: @LucasCorreia Então use como `char []`, ou seja, com a notação de array. Na verdade, em C, ponteiros e arrays dão quase sempre na mesma coisa (há pouquíssimos lugares onde há alguma diferença).

Comment: Ok. Vou fazer o que me sugeriu e marcar a resposta como correta ali. Valeu! Volto assim que tiver novas dúvidas.